# Simplify Boolean Algebra expression $A\overline C + A\overline B + \overline CB$

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

Can anyone explain to me how

$$A\overline C + A\overline B + \overline CB$$

simplifies down to $A\overline B +B \overline C$ ?

Comment: $A\overline{C}$ is the consensus of the other two terms; hence, it is implied by their disjunction.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi. Easier way: use Karnaugh map.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Easier for whom and in what sense?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi. Given arbitrary expression (up to 5 variables), you can write algorithm to reduce it to minimal DNF (or KNF) using Karnaugh maps, but how would you explain the reason for writting $A\overline C$ as two terms? Which intuition is used there? What if the given expression contains very complicated terms you didn't see before?

Comment: See [consensus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem).

Comment: Remark, as a side note please use `\bar A` for single character instead of `\overline`, I get confused by the rendering on my browser because the overline tends to overfill the next character. With overline : $A\overline{C}+A\overline{B}+\overline{C}B$ compared to bar : $A\bar C+A\bar B+\bar CB$.

Comment: @zwim. Sorry if I was too aggresive and rude, I really didn't know bad formatting can cause so many problems.

Comment: @ThePirateBay It's ok really, I even upvoted your answer :p.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Iterated consensus is exceedingly effective for simple examples, and is an algorithm that works for larger examples than those one can effectively deal with when using K-maps.  I've been a great fan of K-maps for forty years, and I'm very familiar with all the major algorithms to compute minimum and minimal-cost DNFs.  All said and done, though, nothing beats consensus for problems like this.  With a little training, you can solve this problem in the time it takes you to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$A\bar C=A\bar C(B+\bar B)=A\bar CB+A\bar C\bar B$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}A\bar C+A\bar B+\bar CB&=A\bar CB+A\bar C\bar B+A\bar B+\bar CB\\&=A\bar B(\bar C+1)+\bar CB(A+1)\\&=A\bar B+\bar CB\end{align}$$

Comment: line 2 should be $(\bar C+1)$ instead of $C+\bar C$, but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @zwim. Fixed typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Fabio Somenzi that there are more efficient ways that using  Karnaugh maps/tables. Nevertheless, in the spirit of SE, where one tries to learn how to solve issues with different methods, and for people that don't know this method, here is a proof using these Karnaugh maps:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{\bar B}&\color{red}{\bar B}\\ 
\hline
\color{red}{A}&A B C &A B \bar C&\bar A \bar B \bar C& A \bar B C\\
\hline
\color{red}{\bar A}&\bar A B C&\bar A B \bar C&\bar A \bar B \bar C&\bar A \bar B C\\
\hline
&\color{red}{C}&\color{red}{\bar C}&\color{red}{\bar C}&\color{red}{C}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

One has only to check that the two expressions have the same Karnaugh table which is:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{\bar B}&\color{red}{\bar B}\\ 
\hline
\color{red}{A}& 0&1&1&1 \\
\hline
\color{red}{\bar A}&0&1&0&0\\
\hline
&\color{red}{C}&\color{red}{\bar C}&\color{red}{\bar C}&\color{red}{C}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Remark:** "Algebraic derivations" like the one given by @PirateBay are almost impossible to find without using this kind of table or similar methods.